# Найти общие курсы, на которые записывались студенты разных годов обучения PANDAS

Tags: pandas

Есть два датасета, в котором данные о студентах "2010" и "2011" года обучения.

У них есть 3 колонки, где указаны курсы по выбору.

1.Необходимо найти курсы, на которые записали студенты обоих годов обучения.

2.Также, **методом исключения**, найти курсы, уникальные для каждого года обучения.

```
students_10 = pd.DataFrame({'course_1': ['SQL', 'Pandas'],
                            'course_2': ['Python', 'Python'],
                            'course_3': ['Pandas', 'SQL']})

students_11 = pd.DataFrame({'course_1': ['Pandas', 'C++'],
                            'course_2': ['C++', 'SQL'],
                            'course_3': ['SQL', 'Pandas']})
```

Общие, в данном случае, ['SQL', 'Pandas'], а уникальные - 'Python' для 10 года и 'C++' для 11 года.

*Интересует также решение для одного датасета, где есть бинарные колонки is_10_year и is_11_year*

Comment: Можно увидеть ваши попытки решения?

Comment: Ну типичная же задача на множества (пересечение множеств, вычитание множеств). Только с данными в `Pandas`. Просто надо подумать - как собрать все данные за год в одно множество. И что потом с полученными множествами делать.